# CodecRegistryError while running blender from Python Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, blender

I am trying to run blender as a background process. I have a script which does some format conversion in blender.

```
    blender --background --python /home/WebRendering/scripts/blender_convertToObj.py -i tempForObjGeneration.iv.wrl -o ObjForAR.obj
```

If I copy paste this line as it is in terminal, the script runs and I get the desired output. But when I try to run it from inside a python script using the subprocess module, I get this error

```
    subprocess.call(blender --background --python /home/scripts/blender_convertToObj.py -i tempForObjGeneration.iv.wrl -o ObjForAR.obj, shell = True) 

    Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
    Color management: using fallback mode for management
    Read new prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.69/config/userpref.blend
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError, \
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I use, shell=False in the subprocess call, I get the error below

```
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
     OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea on, what could be cause of the error?
Also, what is the difference between running a script directly in terminal and running it through subprocess?

Blender Version - 2.69
Python version - 2.7

Comment: Have you put quotes around the command? As blender2.69 uses python 3.4 maybe loading it inside a 2.7 session causes issues?

Comment: @sambler I have tried both quotes and non quotes, not working. Any way to control what version of python is used to execute any specific command?

Comment: Blender will always use the version it is built with, If you have more than one version of python installed they will have different names eg python2.7 python3.4 or use full paths `/usr/local/bin/python3.4` either at the cli `python3.4 myscript` or in the script with `#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4`